# Content not display properly in table

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, jbutton

this is what my text file look like: copy it into a notepad and open in the SSCCE

```
First Name: dan
Last Name: rmadakkk
Phone Number: (348) 794-7329
Email: leo@live.ca
```

Update: Here's what I'm seeing.

[image: wrong]

Here's what I want.

[image: right]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private JTextField Searchtextfield;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField Firstnametext;
    private JTextField lastnametext;
    private JTextField Phonenumbertext;
    private JTextField Emailtext;
    BufferedReader reader;
    DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public Main() throws Exception {

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 32, 650, 365);
        getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);

        JPanel MainPanel = new JPanel();
        MainPanel.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Main", null, MainPanel, null);
        MainPanel.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 42, 604, 217);
        MainPanel.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        String columns[] = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", "Email"};
        tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 4);
        tableModel.setColumnIdentifiers(columns);
        table.setModel(tableModel);

        JButton button = new JButton("Open Txt");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                String line;
                JFileChooser fileload = new JFileChooser();


                if (fileload.showOpenDialog(Main.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    try {
                        File file = fileload.getSelectedFile();
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            tableModel.addRow(line.split(": "));
                        }
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e10) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Buffered Reader issue.");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        button.setBounds(160, 11, 129, 23);
        MainPanel.add(button);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Main frame = new Main();
        frame.setTitle("Phone Book App");
        frame.setSize(640, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not a ton of errors. That's one exception. It means you're operating on a null object.

Comment: im not sure what to do to resolve these problem?

Comment: Checking that every object before a dot isn't null is a good start to finding one that might be.

Comment: Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Either `tableModel` or `line` is null, if we can believe the line you have shown.

Comment: @PaulGrime, `line` has a null check, but I was thinking `tableModel` myself.

Comment: What's at line 300 of your actionPerformed?

Comment: thank for all the help so far. i was able to get everything working but now I have another problem.

the information get added into the table but it not being added properly

this is how it show up


[img]http://i.imgur.com/WTwUzJS.png?1[/img]

it should look like this:

[img]http://i.imgur.com/0013aWN.png[/img]

Comment: What kind of debugging have your done? Did you display each line of text as you read it? Based on the code you posted the format of your data is wrong. But since, once again you refuse to post a SSCCE it is only a guess and the last time I will make a guess because I don't have all this time to waste.

Comment: unrelated (or not): a) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them b) never do any manual sizing/locating of components, instead use a suitable LayoutManager c) don't dump all your code unto us, instead distill a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: `The full code: you can compile and run` - How many times do you need to be told that is NOT a SSCCE??? How many times do you need to be asked to use proper names and a layout manager. You ask for help but don't listen to the advice given. With a proper SSCCE this issue would have been solved in 5 minutes.

Comment: im working on the SSCCE version

Comment: Still using setBounds(). Still using improper Java Variable names. Still not a SSCCE since we don't have access to the text file and we don't know what the format of the text file is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At judging by your snippet, the txt file contains the value of each columnn of your table in one line, so, by reading line by line and adding it to the table model as rows, you're wrongly filling the table.

Besides, `line.split(": ");` returns an array of Strings, taking in consideration your first line in the text snippet you post, `[FirstName][danny]`. If you were to only put the field data, and not the field name, `line.split(": ")[1];` would fix that, however, it will not fix the issue that you're filling rows with single fields of data.

Consider creating a Class, perhaps Contact, as I see the information on your text file belongs to contacts info, read the txt file and create Contact objects, put them in an array, and then instantiate your table model with the data.

A better approach will also incur in you writing your own table model.

UPDATE:
Ok, seems I will put a workaround.

ASSUMING your txt files to be loaded have ALL of them the same format.

```
    First Name: dan
    Last Name: rmadakkk
    Phone Number: (348) 794-7329
    Email: leo@live.ca
```

Check this:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    String line;
    JFileChooser fileload = new JFileChooser();
        if (fileload.showOpenDialog(Main.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            try {
                File file = fileload.getSelectedFile();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                Object[] tableRow = new Object[columnNames.length];
                int column = 0;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    tableData[column++] = line.split(": ")[1];
                    if (column > 3) {
                        tableModel.addRow(tableRow);
                        column = 0;
                    }
                }
                reader.close();
             } catch (IOException e10) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Buffered Reader issue.");
             }
        }
    };
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i try this `tableModel.addRow(line.split(": ") + 1);`

Comment: I never said `line.split(": ") + 1;`, I said `line.split(": ")[1];`, but anyways, do you even read all of my answer? That will not fix your issue at all, I just pointed one of your mistakes...

Anyways, let me edit with a snippet.

Comment: sorry i very new to java. im self teaching my self the language so it hard to follow some of the abbreviation. I am assuming the [1] is a array postion?

Comment: Yes, it states the array position. Try the snippet of code I posted in my edit. BEWARE: it will only work as long as all your txt files have the very SAME format.

And consider what I stated in my first post: create a Class to describe the related fields you're reading in your file.

Comment: i have a issure with this line. `Object[] tableRow = new Object[columnNames.length];`. The error i am getting is ColoumNames cannot be resolved as a varaible.

Comment: Maybe because columnNames doesn't exist? In your code it's called columns, and it's also a local variable, so you gotta check that in order for the snippet to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27711/discussion-between-devendra-danny-ramdayal-and-noe)

Comment: Nvm i figured it out thank for all your help i really appreciate it.